# MVC 5.0 Appnet Identity mixing Code First and Database First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, ef-code-first, ef-database-first

I'm creating a new Web Application based on MVC 5. I have Database and would like to Use Database First workflow. I would like to Use Aspnet Identity new features, but they rely on Code First. Will it be possible to mix, so that i manage Authentication and Authorization with  the new Aspnet Identity, and Database First for all the Business Logic Application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think mixing things isn't the best way. code first and data first they have a reason to be different, might be the best way to solve this is to use a database for the authentication process and another database for the busines logic, hope it helps you

Comment: +1. Did this. Works well and has sense even in a none technical way.

Comment: Actually i don't think is a good idea think about when you want to use Objects of different context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to learn MVC and it is quickly pissing me off.

The way I solved this problem is to:

1. In your main model, add you ADO.NET Entity Data Model
2. In your web.config, change the defaultconnection to the database in MS-SQL.
3. Enable-Migrations on your ApplicationDbContext

Yes, this means there are two connections to the database.  I would love to hear on what is a better way.